# exception when parsing multipart form data

Tags: java, multipartform-data

I am trying to handle a file upload, and I'm using the
com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser class to parse the posted
data (in cos.jar).  However, when I call the constructor for MultipartParser, I get this
exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Corrupt form data: premature ending
    at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:166)
    at com.oreilly.servlet.multipart.MultipartParser.<init>(MultipartParser.java:94)
```

Has anyone seen this before?  From what I read, this means that the
data ended before it found the boundary it was looking for.  How can I
fix this?

I am using cos.jar version 1.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was caused by me calling the MultipartParser constructor twice, by accident.  It failed the second time, since the request had already been processed.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.servlets.com/cos/faq.html

> This indicates there was a problem
>   parsing the POST request submitted by
>   the client. There can be many causes
>   for the problem:
>
> - The client hit the STOP button (not really a problem, but it does cause a
>     premature ending)
> - A bug in the web form
> - A bug in the servlet
> - A bug in the web server
> - A bug in the browser
> - A bug in the com.oreilly.servlet library itself
>
> History has shown the web server to be
>   the most frequent cause of problems
>   probably because there are so many
>   different servers and few vendors
>   appear to test their binary upload
>   capability.
>
> First, make sure your client isn't
>   hitting the STOP button. Then, check
>   if your problem is already posted on
>   the "Servlet bugs you need to know
>   about" resource on this site. If it's
>   not well known, then you get to be
>   among the first to learn about it! And
>   you can share your discovery with us
>   here!
>
> Second, see if the upload works using
>   the provided upload.html form and
>   DemoRequestUploadServlet.java class.
>   Some people have found bugs in their
>   form that caused problems. Testing
>   this combination will see if that's
>   the case. One user, Duke Takle, found
>   this exception was caused by a
>   redirect: *I was experiencing the same
>   "premature ending" as Albert Smith.
>   What I've found is that the problem
>   was isolated to I.E. 5.0. The
>   application that troubled me was doing
>   a redirect after the construction of a
>   MultipartRequest. It looks like this
>   construction went well except on I.E.
>   5.0 the browser attempted to make the request again and by that time the
>   ServletInputStream was empty. I've
>   modified the application to simply
>   write the needed response instead of
>   redirecting. This problem was observed
>   and fixed as described in Tomcat 4.0
>   and Weblogic 6.1.* Other users have
>   found bugs in their handling servlet
>   where they call request.getParameter()
>   instead of
>   multipartRequest.getParameter(), and
>   some servers falsely read the input
>   stream when their getParameter() is
>   called causing an "unexpected end of
>   part".